# Count downloads with two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two table and like to know how many downloads a certain name has. Here are my tables

Table "names"

```
ID | name
==========
 1 | foo
 2 | bar
 3 | zoo
 4 | luu
```

Table "downloads"

```
ID | name_id | timestamp
=========================
 1 | 1       | 1394041682
 2 | 4       | 1394041356
 3 | 1       | 1394041573
 4 | 3       | 1394041981
 5 | 1       | 1394041683
```

Result should be:

```
ID | name | downloads
=====================
 1 | foo  | 3
 2 | bar  | 0
 3 | zoo  | 1
 4 | luu  | 1
```

This should be pretty easy...

Comment: What dbms are you using?

Comment: mysql, sry. I've added a tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is pretty easy.
Just [`JOIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) tables and [`COUNT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/counting-rows.html) rows. Don't forget to [`GROUP BY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html), and `COUNT(timestamp)` so you could get zero if there isn't any

```
  SELECT n.ID,
         n.name,
         COUNT(timestamp) as downloads
    FROM names n 
         LEFT JOIN downloads d 
              ON d.name_id = n.id
GROUP BY n.ID,
         n.name
ORDER BY n.ID;
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/986acb/1)

Comment: Thanks, this works, now I have a more complex problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22206379/count-values-over-m-n-connected-tables-in-sql