# Count values over m/n connected tables in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have four tables and like to know how many locations and downloads a certain name has.
`names` and `locations` are connected via the `names_locations` table

Here are my tables:

Table "`names`"

```
ID | name
=========
 1 | foo
 2 | bar
 3 | zoo
 4 | luu
```

Table "`locations`"

```
ID | location
=============
 1 | Hamburg
 2 | New York
 3 | Singapore
 4 | Tokio
```

Table "`names_locations`"

```
ID | location_id | name_id
==========================
 1 | 1           | 1
 2 | 1           | 2
 3 | 2           | 2
 4 | 3           | 3
 5 | 1           | 2
```

Table "`downloads`"

```
ID | name_id | timestamp
=========================
 1 | 1       | 1394041682
 2 | 4       | 1394041356
 3 | 1       | 1394041573
 4 | 3       | 1394041981
 5 | 1       | 1394041683
```

Result should be:

```
ID | name | locations | downloads
=================================
 1 | foo  | 1         | 3
 2 | bar  | 3         | 0
 3 | zoo  | 1         | 1
 4 | luu  | 0         | 1
```

Here's my attempt (without the downloads column):

```
SELECT names.*, 
       Count(names_locations.location_id) AS location 
FROM   names 
       LEFT JOIN names_locations 
              ON names.ID = names_locations.name_id 
GROUP  BY names.ID
```

Comment: Please update your question with your attempt(s) to solve this.

Comment: eerily familiar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22205797/count-downloads-with-two-tables

Comment: @AgRizzo yes that was my previous questions

Comment: I could not understand how the count of locations for id=1 is 1 while it is 3 for id=2 .. if we are considering distinct locations should it not be 2 for id=2?

Comment: @Nishant there's a third `id=2` in the names_locations table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this would work.

```
SELECT n.id,
       n.name,
       COUNT(DISTINCT l.id) AS locations,
       COUNT(DISTINCT d.id) AS downloads
FROM names n LEFT JOIN names_location nl
  ON n.id = nl.name_id
LEFT JOIN downloads dl
  ON n.id = dl.name_id
LEFT JOIN locations l
  ON l.id = nl.location_id
GROUP BY n.id, n.name
```

Comment: yep. I had forgotten the distinct though, you got it.

Comment: This gives location count as 2 for id = 2

Comment: I did assume they wanted to match distinct location, and maybe should not have since they show 3 in their desired output.  Replacing COUNT(DISTINCT l.id) with COUNT(DISTINCT nl.id) would change the count to match their example output.

Answer (score 1):

All of those seem to work. here's another one.

```
SELECT 
  a.ID,
  a.name,
  COUNT(c.location) AS locations,
  COUNT(d.timestamp) AS downloads 
FROM names AS a
  LEFT JOIN names_locations AS b on a.ID=b.name_id
  LEFT JOIN locations AS c ON b.location_id=c.ID
  LEFT JOIN downloads AS d ON a.ID=d.name_id
GROUP BY a.name
```

Comment: +------+------+-----------+-----------+
| ID   | name | locations | downloads |
+------+------+-----------+-----------+
|    2 | bar  |         3 |         0 |
|    1 | foo  |         3 |         3 |
|    4 | luu  |         0 |         1 |
|    3 | zoo  |         1 |         1 |
+------+------+-----------+-----------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec) .. i ran it and got the output as above, is this the expected output..

Comment: yep, as I commented in @Alden's answer, I have forgotten the `DISTINCT()` part which was needed to have the right result. Hence my upvote of his answer. And it's against my principles to simply update my answer with another one's answer

Comment: i don't think its due to distinct.. because the location count for id=2 is 3.. and it has a location_id that is repeated.

Comment: oh you're right... hmmm.. that's.. unexpected. Maybe he want the sum of the ids? :p

Comment: posted a solution that gives the desirred o/p

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
  t.id,t.n AS name,
  count(location_id) AS locations,
  t.downloads
FROM names_location 
RIGHT JOIN 
 (SELECT 
    names.id AS id,
    names.name AS n, 
    count(timestamp) AS downloads 
  FROM names
    LEFT JOIN downloads ON names.id = downloads.name_id
    GROUP BY id) AS t 
ON t.id = names_location.name_id
GROUP BY t.id
```

Output:

```
+------+------+-----------+-----------+
| id   | name | locations | downloads |
+------+------+-----------+-----------+
|    1 | foo  |         1 |         3 |
|    2 | bar  |         3 |         0 |
|    3 | zoo  |         1 |         1 |
|    4 | luu  |         0 |         1 |
+------+------+-----------+-----------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```